# Can Docker be installed on SUSE 11 SP3

Tags: docker, suse

I have read *Docker Quick Start* at www.suse.com, however, the guideline only applies to SUSE 12 SP1.  Does it have a way to install Docker on SUSE 11 SP3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not according to [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7211), since the minimum kernel is 3.8 (and SUSE 11 SP3 uses kernel [3.0.x](https://wiki.microfocus.com/index.php/Kernel_versions)